# After installing NuGet package PagedList.Mvc, application stopped on deployment server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, pagedlist

I am working on an MVC 5 application and it was running perfectly fine before I started using the Pager from PagedList.Mvc. After I used this Pager, the application works fine on the development server but when I publish it to the file system and deploy it on another server, it gives me the following error:

`Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Mvc Version 4.0.0.0`

Please help me resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably because PagedList.Mvc is compiled against System.Web.Mvc Version 4.0.0.0.

Try using bindingRedirect:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Just update line `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.1" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>` with your proper versions.